# MaraDNS zone transfers

Tags: dns-zone

When attempting to do a zone transfer with MaraDNS 2.0.13, I'm getting the following in the logs:

```
Sep 29 00:50:24 ns1 maradns.etc_maradns_mararc:  Log: Message received, processing<br>
Sep 29 00:50:24 ns1 maradns.etc_maradns_mararc: Query from: XX.XX.XX.XX Udomain.com.<br>
Sep 29 00:50:24 ns1 maradns.etc_maradns_mararc:  Log: Bad query received: \260\346\000\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\013<11 character domain>\003com\000\000\374\000\001<br>
Sep 29 00:50:24 ns1 maradns.etc_maradns_mararc: From IP: XX.XX.XX.XX<br>
Sep 29 00:50:24 ns1 maradns.etc_maradns_mararc:  Log: not_impl in proc_query<br>
```

The zoneserver process is running and listening on port 53, and the appropriate fields in the MaraDNS config file (`tcp_convert_acl`, `zone_transfer_acl`, etc.) are set properly, and the querying servers' IPs are included in `zone_transfer_acl`.  MaraDNS has worked really well for me for several years, but this is the first time I've had to set it up for zone transfers.  I get the same result from my secondary DNS provider, "dig axfr", and even from MaraDNS's own **fetchzone** tool.

I'd really rather not move off of Mara, so does anyone have any ideas where else to look to solve this issue?